# Is the dimension of variety a topological invariant?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider the dimension of the variety $Y$ defined by $f=x_0+x_1$.

Now I am really confused by its dimension. If we treat it as a variety in $\mathbf{P}^1$, then its dimension is 
$$\dim Y=\dim S(Y)-1=\dim k[x_0,x_1]-\mathrm{height} (f)-1=2-1-1=0$$

Now, treat it as the variety in $\mathbf{P}^2$. After similar calculation, we have 
$$\dim Y=1.$$

However, we can construct the injective continuous map
$$\varphi:\mathbf{P}^1\rightarrow \mathbf{P}^2$$
by sending $[x_0:x_1]$ to $[x_0:x_1:0]$. It is easy to verify that $\varphi$ induces the homeomorphism from $Z(f)$ in $\mathbf{P}^1$ to $Z(f)$ in $\mathbf{P}^2$.

However, I think the dimension is a topological invariant since the dimension has an equivalent topological definition. So I made some stupid mistake somewhere. Please point it out. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "treat as a variety in" different projective spaces? Also, $Z(x_0 + x_1)$ is NOT empty in $\mathbf P^1$, it contains the point $[1 : -1]$.

Comment: @TabesBridges Fixed the latter mistake. Thanks! For your first question, what I mean is that we can treat $x_0+x_1$ as the polynomial in $k[x_0,x_1]$ and $k[x_0,x_1,x_2]$. So we can define two varieties in $\mathbf{P}^1$ and $\mathbf{P}^2$ respectively.

Comment: Right, but what you need to understand is that varieties defined by the "same" equation in two different rings don't have anything to do with one another until you relate those rings by a homomorphism and show how the equation transforms. I think what you are looking for here is something like that when you restrict the polynomial $x_0 + x_1 \in k[x_0,x_1,x_2]$ to an appropriate line (embedded $\mathbf P^1$) in $\mathbf P^2$, it restricts to $x_0 + x_1 \in k[x_0,x_1]$. So just find the right quotient map $k[x_0,x_1,x_2] \to k[x_0,x_1]$, but...

Comment: ...note that you are being somewhat glib with using the same variables on both sides, so the map with kernel generated by $x_2$ may or may not be the right one (actually it probably is here...). So the punchline is that while your equation cuts out a line (a $1$-dimensional variety) in $\mathbf P^2$, its restriction to an embedded line is just a point (i.e. the intersection of those two lines).

Comment: @TabesBridges Thank you very much. I think I know where I am wrong. Merry Christmas!